Analyzer exclude also suppresses errors
In my analysis_options.yaml I wrote an exclude for generated files
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/**.g.dart

I noticed that it also suppresses errors though, not just linting warnings. This is a problem for me as I wrote the code generator myself, and I would like to see the errors that are there while not seeing the linting warnings.
How do I do that?
